# React/Redux/ReactDnd - Error: removeComponentAsRefFrom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-dnd

I am trying to apply a basic example of react DnD to my project (as a proof of concept) and am running into some issues. I am using this example - https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd/tree/master/examples/02%20Drag%20Around/Naive . which just let you drag around some divs inside a box.

So I have an outer component (Note: this is a few component levels up from the actual drag component) which is basically the whole page (this is just for testing a POC at first) which looks like so:

```
 import { DropTarget, DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';

const boxTarget = {
    drop(props, monitor, component) {
        const item = monitor.getItem();
        const delta = monitor.getDifferenceFromInitialOffset();
        const left = Math.round(item.left + delta.x);
        const top = Math.round(item.top + delta.y);

        component.moveBox(item.id, left, top);
    }
};

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)
// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@DropTarget('CLA_DRAG', boxTarget, (connect) => ({
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget()
}))
export default class GenericPlatformComponent extends React.Component {
    ...

    render() {
        const { connectDropTarget } = this.props;

        return connectDropTarget(
            <div>
                {this.getBuilders()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So pretty close to the examples container, just using a string for now instead of that constant in @`DropTarget` . The getBuilders just renders other components inside. **I Ran this component before creating the DragSource component and everything was running fine**.

So, a few components down I just added the react DnD syntax to the component I want to be draggable like so :

```
 import { DragSource } from 'react-dnd';

 const boxSource = {
    beginDrag(props) {
        const { id, left, top } = props;

        return { id, left, top };
    }
 };

// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
@DragSource('CLA_DRAG', boxSource, (connect, monitor) => ({
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
}))
export default class SearchResult extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { connectDragSource } = this.props;

        return connectDragSource(
            <div key={this.props.key}>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={2} sm={2} md={1} lg={1} >
                            <div style={tempThumbnail}>
                                Picture Here
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs={10} sm={10} md={11} lg={11} >
                            <DescriptionBlock result={this.props.result} {...this.props} />
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So with all this, I am getting this error on the console (the app is stopping rendering too).

```
bundle.js:29605 Uncaught (in promise) Error: removeComponentAsRefFrom(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be removing a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded (details: react-refs-must-have-owner).(…)
```

What is strange is the dragsource isn't even called onto the dom yet, so I have no idea where to start with this error. Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Seems from a bit of googling to often be an issue with importing React twice on the same page so I'd check to make sure you aren't doing that somewhere weird (see https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/648 and https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/606)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you omitted it, but you should be importing React in both of your examples:

```
import React from 'react'
```

Comment: Yes thank you, i took out that bit of the code to cut down the amount of code I am showing, but it is there in the real code itself.

Comment: Alright, sorry about that. I'm not familiar enough with react-dnd or this issue with refs, hope someone else can shed more insight.

Comment: No problem, was a perfectly valid concern, thank you for trying!